# How can I pass a response to my parse function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using cloudscraper to scrape a cloudflare protected url which works using:

```
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get(url).text
```

How can I pass this response in scrapy to my parse function?  Can I somehow put this in a scrapy.Request()?

Comment: It depends where it is running. If you run this in a spider callback, then `yield from self.parse(Response(url, body=response))` should work. You may need to convert `response` to bytes beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta to send data from Request yield to parse function. [Meta docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html).

**Example:**

```
#inside some method:
yield Scrapy.Request(
    url='http://example.com'
    meta={
        'key': 'yourdata'
    }
)


#parse method
def parse(self, response):
   data = response.meta.get('key')
```

Comment: At work and haven't got a chance to test yet.  But if I pass the response data from 'response = scraper.get(url).text' into 'yourdata' what is the point of including the URL in the request if I already have the data I need?

Comment: I can make it work doing this 

"yield scrapy.Request("https://quotes.toscrape.com/",
                             meta={'key': response}, dont_filter=True)"

But I use a rotating residential proxy service and this burns up bandwidth for no reason.  Can I just pass something over to parse (and nested_parse after parse completes) without using Scrapy request at all?  Scrapy.Request is basically useless to me since I have to use cloudscraper to get the data.